# Docker build react, module not found

Tags: node.js, linux, docker, npm

I can't run docker container correctly. After run container I see an error:

Creating an optimized production build...
**Failed to compile.

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './src/theme' in '/usr/bin/app/src'

make: *** [Makefile:16: react-build] Error 1**

String 16 is `docker run -it -v $(shell realpath out):/usr/bin/app/build frontend-temp bash -c "npm run build"`

nginx-container/Dockerfile:

```
FROM nginx
COPY out /usr/share/nginx/html
COPY version.html /usr/share/nginx/html/version.html
COPY nginx-container/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
COPY nginx-container/default.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
```

build-container/Dockerfile:

```
FROM debian:buster-slim

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y curl && \
    curl -fsSL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_16.x | bash - &&\
    apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y nodejs

RUN mkdir -p /usr/bin/app
RUN npm install -g npm

COPY web-application/src /usr/bin/app/src
COPY web-application/package.json /usr/bin/app/
COPY web-application/package-lock.json /usr/bin/app/
COPY web-application/public /usr/bin/app/public

WORKDIR /usr/bin/app
RUN npm install --force
#CMD ["npm", "run", "build"]
EXPOSE 8080
```

and final makefile:

```
all: react-build web-app

DOCKERTAG?='cloud-interface:latest'
GIT_VERSION := $(shell git describe --abbrev=7 --dirty --always --tags)

web-app:
    echo $(GIT_VERSION) > version.html
    docker build -t $(DOCKERTAG) -f nginx-container/Dockerfile .
    rm -rf out
    docker rmi -f frontend-temp

react-build: build-container/Dockerfile web-application/src web-application/package-lock.json web-application/package.json web-application/public
    docker build --no-cache -t frontend-temp -f build-container/Dockerfile .
    rm -rf out
    mkdir out
    docker run -it -v $(shell realpath out):/usr/bin/app/build frontend-temp bash -c "npm run build"

.PHONY: clean
```

what's wrong, any suggestion to fix it?